# Can I bootcamp my mac with only a product key from windows8.1?

Tags: bootcamp

I recently got myself a product key and I really wanna bootcamp my mac but I can't find how with only the product key... Please don't tell me I lost €70 on that..?

Comment: Have a look at: [Use Windows 8.1 on your Mac with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201457)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the [mediacreationtool.exe](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) which will allow you to download the .iso or create the USB flash drive.

I believe you want an iso. If you use the mediacreationtool to create a USB flash drive, it will not work on a Mac. You need to burn the iso to a DVD or use Boot Camp Assistant to create the USB.

Of course you will need to execute the mediacreationtool from a machine booted to Windows. If you do not have such a machine, you can install a temporary evaluation copy of Windows Enterprise 8.1. The iso can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-8-1-enterprise).

To be clear. You download the 64 bit Windows Enterprise 8.1 as an iso. You use the iso to install Windows to your Mac. Boot to Windows and download the Media Creation Tool. Run this tool to download a iso of the Home or Pro version of Windows 8.1. This iso should work with your product key. You then erase the installed Enterprise Windows and install the Home or Pro Windows using the Product Key.

> Note: For almost all Macs, you want the 64 bit version of windows.

Comment: But when I download the mediacreationtool.exe I don't have to put my product key.. and when I try opening it, it says not able to open on mac.. can you help me please

Comment: Didn't read the last part sorry!

Comment: When I download the temmorary evaluation copy of WIndows, I doest open..

Comment: @kemelkoala: You are not suppose to open it. I assume you downloaded a 64 bit Window 8.1 Enterprise iso file. You are suppose to install Windows so you can run the media creation tool. Read my answer. I updated it.